# How can I send a query to a URL using Curl POST Using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I wrote a query through 'postman' which looks like this

```
POST: http://someurl  

{
    "elasticQuery": //Elastic Query is a user defined field.
    {
        "_source": [ "field 1", "field 2", "field 3" ],
        "query": 
        {
            "match_all":{}
        }
    }, 
    "index": "indexName", 
    "scroll": "True"
}
```

This returns lots of JSON formatted documents from the site with 3 given fields. 
I am wondering how I would format this query using PHP to do a curl call and recieve the same documents.

I am not sure if this is even possible but your help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "YOUR_URL_HERE",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"elasticQuery\":{\"_source\":[\"field 1\",\"field 2\",\"field 3\"],\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}},\"index\":\"indexName\",\"scroll\":\"True\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Remember to replace the CURLOPT_URL string with your own URL. As a further tip, you can get Postman to generate this for you. With the request open in a tab, towards the top right below the "Send" button, there's a small bit of text which says "Code". Select it and you should have the option to generate PHP cURL.